# A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gesture-handler'

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

Hey guys I've been trying for so long to solve this issue but unfortunately i haven't figured out how, hope you guys can help me please.
so i've a **react-native project** with my friend , and one of my friend add
react-native-gesture-handler package for our uses and he doesn't have no errors or issues with this package, but when i pulled his changes and try to run the app using
`npx react-native-run-android` i got this error in that you can see in this picture,
i've trying to install the package using `npm i react-native-gesture-handler` and it's doesn't show any errors while installing it , but as i already said, the issue was when im starting to run the app using `npx react-native-run-android`

hopfully you guys can help me solve it, thanks a lot.

[image: ScreenShot of the error]
[image: Continue ScreenShot of the errorC]

Comment: were you able to solve this?, am facing it too on a clean app.

Comment: Yes buddy, im not sure but i think that I needed to upgrade my node js version,  im not sure what version number sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you linked it to react-native after installing?
e.g. `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

If not, try that > clean cache > build > run.

See here for more details on installation: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/#installation

Also confirm both of you are on the same React version(s).

Comment: react-native -v in the terminal or check your package.json file and look for react, react-native packages.

Comment: i did link it but it doesn't helped .
i'll check if his version same as me using `npm view react version`

Comment: I've confirmed that we both have the same react version,is there any other solution options?

Comment: In the build.gradle file, make sure you have the same compileSDK version as your buddy.  There is also targetSDK, confirm, it is the same. In your error screenshot, the second part notes that is the issue. It may resolve your initial issue too, as there is 2 errors thrown.

Also, in SDK manager - confirm you have the correct SDK version installed - is compileSDK is 29 then make sure you have that SDK ver.

Comment: hey buddy , thank you for your help , im not sure how do i check my compile sdk version, is the api level is means the compile sdk version?
if yes then i do have version 31 and the build gradle is set to 30

Comment: I saw that the first error talking about the kotlin that cannot be initialize,  do you know what that means?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error

`npm i react-native-gesture-handler`

fixed it