# A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-gesture-handler'

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.
> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gesture-handler'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

I tried this stackoverflow solution also → `https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294898/12071002`

But the link is removed maybe in newer version

[image]

Tried to build project with Android Studio also but the issue with `compileSdkVersion` as in the image or same with running with `npx react-native run-android`

[image]

or i didn't think these are related to this issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if I can help, but I got issue with `react-native-gesture-handler` when I upgraded the `gradle to 7.4.1`.
it fixed it self after a `npm upgrade`.
An other thing to try is to upgrade android studio.

Wich react-native are you using?

Comment: sorry i forget to mention this on question

but i am using 
Gradle = gradle-7.5.1,
JDK = Microsoft\jdk-11.0.18.10 (openjdk as installtion in docs),
"react-native": "0.71.3", (latest as from npx react-native)

Comment: and i am using the latest Android studio maybe because i update it just 2 days ago when i get notify from android studio

Comment: Wich verion of react-native-gesture-handler are you using?
Tried to uninstall it and install it again?

Comment: "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",